# Is it possible to parallelise creation of a dict in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I actually have this code to create a dict.

```py
import multiprocessing
cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)
items = data['id'].unique()

def compute_weight(item):
    return sum(data[data['id'] == item])
weights = pool.map(compute_weight, items)

my_dict = {k, v for k, v in zip(items, weights)}
```

My question is: is there a way to directly create the dictionary with multiprocessing?

Comment: Why do you want to use multiprocessing? Would it not be much better to use a better data structure / algorithm instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you don't need the loop.

Use

```
my_dict = dict(zip(items, weights))
```

which should be considerably faster because it pushes the loop down to the C level (in case of CPython)

Comment: Tried like `python -m timeit -s "a=range(1000)" "dict(zip(a, a))"`, made it about factor 1.4 faster.